# How can Nginx be upgraded without dropping any requests?

Tags: unix, nginx, internals

According to [the Nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine):

> If you need to replace nginx binary
>   with a new one (when upgrading to a
>   new version or adding/removing server
>   modules), you can do it without any
>   service downtime - no incoming
>   requests will be lost.

My coworker and I were trying to figure out: **how does that work?**. We know (we think) that:

- Only one process can be listening on port 80 at a time
- Nginx creates a socket and connects it to port 80
- A parent process and any of its children can all bind to the same socket, which is how Nginx can have multiple worker children responding to requests

We also did some experiments with Nginx, like this:

- Send a `kill -USR2` to the current master process
- Repeatedly run `ps -ef | grep unicorn` to see any unicorn processes, with their own pids and their parent pids
- Observe that the new master process is, at first, a child of the old master process, but when the old master process is gone, the new master process has a ppid of 1.

So apparently the new master process can listen to the same socket as the old one while they're both running, because at that time, the new master is a child of the old master. But somehow the new master process can then become... um... nobody's child?

I assume this is standard Unix stuff, but **my understanding of processes and ports and sockets is pretty darn fuzzy**. Can anybody explain this in better detail? Are any of our assumptions wrong? And is there a book I can read to really grok this stuff?

Comment: It should be noted that according to the nginx docs, both the old and new master processes are handling connections until you send a WINCH signal to the old master process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For specifics: http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/Sockets/TcpSockets.htm describes the C library for TCP sockets.

I think the key is that after a process forks while holding a socket file descriptor, the parent and child are both able to call accept() on it.

So here's the flow.  Nginx, started normally:

1. Calls socket() and bind() and listen() to set up a socket, referenced by a file descriptor (integer).
2. Starts a thread that calls accept() on the file descriptor in a loop to handle incoming connections.

Then Nginx forks.  The parent keeps running as usual, but the child immediately execs the new binary.  exec() wipes out the old program, memory, and running threads, but inherits open file descriptors: see http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve.  I suspect the exec() call passes the number of the open file descriptor as a command line parameter.

The child, started as part of an upgrade:

1. Reads the open file descriptor's number from the command line.
2. Starts a thread that calls accept() on the file descriptor in a loop to handle incoming connections.
3. Tells the parent to drain (stop accept()ing, and finish existing connections), and to die.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how nginx does it, but basically, it could just `exec` the new binary, carrying the listening socket with it the new process (actually, it remains the same process, it just replaces the program executing in it). The listening socket has a backlog of incoming connections, and as long as it's fast enough to boot up, it should be able to start processing them before it overflows. If not, it could probably fork first, exec, and wait for it to boot up to the point where it's ready to process incoming requests, then hand over the command of the listening socket (file descriptors are inherited when forking, both have access to it) via some internal mechanism, before exiting. Noting your observations, this looks like what it's doing (if your parent process dies, your ppid is reassigned to init, i.e. pid 1)

If it has multiple processes competing to accept on the same listening socket (again, I have no idea how nginx does it, perhaps it has a dispatching process?), then you could replace them one by one, by ordering them to exec the new program, as above, but one at a time, as to never drop the ball. Note that during such a process there would never be any new pids or parent/child relationship changes.

At least, I think that's probably how I would do it, off the top of my head.